# Python executemany function

Tags: python, sql, oracle, executemany

I have a problem when running `executemany` with cx_oracle

WHen I run the following statement, I receive `ORA-01036: illeagal variablename/number`

`infotext_list` is a list of strings that should be compared with the `"SOMETHING"`
it looks like ["abc", "bcd", "def", ...] and every string in it should be compared with the SOMETHING in that other databasetable!

```
insert_stmt = 'INSERT INTO data_table (...) SELECT ... FROM other_table WHERE SOMETHING = ? '
curs.executemany(insert_stmt, infotext_list)
```

If I iterate over the `infotext_list` and use the standard `execute()` method it just works fine but it takes forever.

Comment: what is `infotext_list` and what is the exact error message you get.

Comment: Noone any suggestions? :/

Answer (score 0):

A couple things I changed to get this to work for me.

1- Change infotext_list to be a list of [mappings or sequences](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.executemany)

```
infotext_list = [("abc",), ("bcd",), ("def",)] --notice the extra , inside the ()
```

or

```
infotext_list = [{'value':"abc"}, {'value':"bcd"}, {'value':"def"}]
```

2- Change ? to be :value if you want to use a mapping or :1 (or any other :name you want) if you want to use a sequence

Both of these work for me

```
infotext_list = [("abc",), ("bcd",), ("def",)]
insert_stmt = 'INSERT INTO data_table (...) SELECT ... FROM other_table WHERE SOMETHING = :1 '
curs.executemany(insert_stmt, infotext_list)

infotext_list = [{'value':"abc"}, {'value':"bcd"}, {'value':"def"}]
insert_stmt = 'INSERT INTO data_table (...) SELECT ... FROM other_table WHERE SOMETHING = :value '
curs.executemany(insert_stmt, infotext_list)
```

I have a short write up on using cx_Oracle for crud operations [here](http://learncodeshare.net/2015/06/26/insert-crud-using-cx_oracle/).